# Winforms DataGridView CellEndEdit Loops

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

For an assignment, we're creating a simple spreadsheet program, similar to Excel. The cells in my DataGridView are editable by the user, and multiple things happen when the user edits a cell. 
Similar to Excel, if you were to type `=A1` into cell A2, A2's value changes to be equal to the value of cell A1, and the text that the user sees updates to reflect this. However, A2's text property needs to remain as `=A1` in case A1's value changes.
While debugging my code, I noticed that my `CellEndEdit` function was looping through twice, although there are no loops involved.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        RealCell cell = spreadsheet.GetCell(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex) as RealCell;

        //set the spreadsheet cell's text to reflect the user's edit
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value != null)
        {
            cell.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
        }
        MenuVisibility();
    }
```

This is a big problem, because it resets the cell's text once more than it should.
Are `CellEndEdit` functions supposed to loop through twice? How can I stop this from happening? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure both `CellEndEdit` events are for the same cell?  Also, is there any chance that you're attaching the method to the `CellEndEdit` event more than once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CellEndEdit` will be triggered when changing the cell value.

So in your case, input value to A1, trigger `CellEndEdit`

Then your code set A2 cell = A1's value, trigger another `CellEndEdit`

You can add a bool to control if you need to suppress the event manually.

Comment: Eric and Ann L. were both right. I ended up just not linking my `CellEndEdit` to the event, so that it only triggered when the value was changed. A bool control would have worked too, I think.